# Terraform loop through multiple providers(accounts) - invokation through module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

i have a use case where need help to use for_each to loop through multiple providers( AWS accounts & regions) and this is a module, the TF will be using hub and spoke model.

[image]

below is the TF Pseudo code i would like to achieve.

```
    module.tf
    ---------
      app_accounts = [
{ "account" : "53xxxx08", "app_vpc_id" : "vpc-0fxxxxxfec8", "role" : "xxxxxxx", "profile" : "child1"},
{ "account" : "53xxxx08", "app_vpc_id" : "vpc-0fxxxxxfec8", "role" : "xxxxxxx", "profile" : "child2"}
                      ]
```

below are the provider and resource files, pleas ignore the variables and output files, as its not relevant here

```
provider.tf
------------
provider "aws" {
  for_each = var.app_accounts
  alias = "child"
  profile = each.value.role
}
```

here is the main resouce block where i want to multiple child accounts against single master account, so i want to iterate through the loop

```
resource "aws_route53_vpc_association_authorization" "master" {
    provider = aws.master
    vpc_id  = vpc_id
    zone_id = zone_id
}

resource "aws_route53_zone_association" "child" {
  provider = aws.child
  vpc_id  = vpc_id
  zone_id = zone_id
}
```

any idea on how to achieve this, please? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to define it statically.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin yes it wont work, for_loop is not accepted in the providers.

Comment: That's correct. You can't have dynamic providers.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to achieve your goal in Terraform is to define a shared module representing the objects that should be present in a single account and then to call that module once for each account, passing a different provider configuration into each.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "master"

  # ...
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "example1"

  profile = "example1"
}

module "example1" {
  source = "./modules/account"

  account    = "53xxxx08"
  app_vpc_id = "vpc-0fxxxxxfec8"

  providers = {
    aws        = aws.example1
    aws.master = aws.master
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "example2"

  profile = "example2"
}

module "example2" {
  source = "./modules/account"

  account    = "53xxxx08"
  app_vpc_id = "vpc-0fxxxxxfec8"

  providers = {
    aws        = aws.example2
    aws.master = aws.master
  }
}
```

The `./modules/account` directory would then contain the resource blocks describing what should exist in each individual account. For example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws, aws.master ]
    }
  }
}

variable "account" {
  type = string
}

variable "app_vpc_id" {
  type = string
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  # (omitting the provider argument will associate
  # with the default provider configuration, which
  # is different for each instance of this module)
  # ...
}

resource "aws_route53_vpc_association_authorization" "master" {
  provider = aws.master

  vpc_id  = var.app_vpc_id
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example.id
}

resource "aws_route53_zone_association" "child" {
  provider = aws.master

  vpc_id  = var.app_vpc_id
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example.id
}
```

(I'm not sure if you actually intended `var.app_vpc_id` to be the VPC specified for those zone associations, but my goal here is only to show the general pattern, not to show a fully-working example.)

Using a shared module in this way allows to avoid repeating the definitions for each account separately, and keeps each account-specific setting specified in only one place (either in a `provider "aws"` block or in a `module` block).

There is no way to make this more dynamic within the Terraform language itself, but if you expect to be adding and removing accounts regularly and want to make it more systematic then you could use code generation for the root module to mechanically produce the `provider` and `module` block for each account, to ensure that they all remain consistent and that you can update them all together in case you need to change the interface of the shared module in a way that will affect all of the calls.